# Google Cloud Storage SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: google-cloud-storage, socket-timeout-exception

Doing a POC for using Google Cloud Storage.

We are testing archiving with Rubrik to Google and a few times a week I am seeing SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out.

The status.cloud.google.com site do not show any outages. Before I request for paid support is there any other way I can investigate what it happening?

Comment: I think we are going to have to look at the calls/APIs being made to GCS and what the high level architecture looks like.  High level questions would include what kinds of operations are timing out, how much data is involved, where are you seeing the error.  I'd also start looking at the Cloud Logging logs to see if there is more information there.  Are you using Client Libraries or making direct REST calls?  Where are the GCS clients running?  (on premises, in GCP or elsewhere).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am fairly new to GCP. The Rubrik appliance has the function built in. You just need to setup the key. Its about 10-20 gigs for testing going from onprem to GCS. The Rubrik has the occasional time out errors when sending the archival backup data. Sadly the error logs and Rubrik knowledge base only indicate GCS timeout.  I will take a look at the Cloud Logging logs.